# data-os-animation : Animation in and then out?

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to incorporate some text that bouncesIn after 3 seconds, stays for a couple seconds then zoomsOut. I thought I would just be able to do this:

```
<section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInDown" data-os-animation-delay="3s" data-os-animation="zoomOutDown" data-os-animation-delay="1s">
    <p id="helper">Filler Text</p>
</section>
```

But apparently I cannot, how would I do this?

Would JQuery be needed - I do know how to do this in JQuery (I think) but I am trying to avoid it as it really isn't a strong point of mine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: to be clear, do you have any documentation that says using data attributes alone would produce this effect? I've never heard of that without some kind of library to support it. You may want to look into css keyframes and animation. what you want would be pretty easy to achieve with keyframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this sort of thing. For this I used **CSS @keyframes**, rather than **JQuery**.

See below:

```
<!-- custom fonts - DON'T NEED FOR THE EFFECT --> 
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700,800,900,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,400italic,600,600italic,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- custom fonts - DON'T NEED FOR THE EFFECT -->

    <div class="main-content">
      <span class="bounced-word anim_1">Bounce then leave</span>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.main-content {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-content .bounced-word {
  color: #56baff;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Titillium Web";
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 230px;
  transform: translate3d(0, -200px, 0);
  width: 100%;
}
.main-content .anim_1 {
  animation: 2s bounced-word infinite, 8s hide infinite;
}

@keyframes bounced-word {
  8% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -45px, 0) scaleY(0.4);
    transform-origin: left bottom 0;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -110px, 0) scaleY(1.4);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scaleY(0.6);
    transform-origin: left bottom 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scaleY(1.2);
    transform-origin: left bottom 0;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scaleY(1);
    transform-origin: left bottom 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes hide {
  0%, 24% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  25%, 50% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50%, 75% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  75%, 100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

This can be seen live here: https://jsfiddle.net/billy_farroll/y27hkq8y/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I managed to create something similar (not as graceful as yours) on my own after researching CSS Keyframes for about an hour. Thank you for your help!